# wav to m4a conversion via QuickTime with Automator

Tags: applescript, automator, quicktime

I have a bunch of huge .wav files which I want to convert to .m4a files via QuickTime export function. 
As there are a lot of wav files I'd like to automate this process with Automator. 
Could you please help me this task? The QuickTime player looks to be not recordable app for automator this is why I have to use Applescript which I do not know.

What I need is "Quick Action" which will be right click file/finder action: upon right click on a file I will choose "convert to m4a"

In my understanding the automator should get the file name and then export it as "Audio only"  via Quicktime player.

In my primitive understanding it would be something like this -

```
tell application "QuickTime player"
    activate
    tell export rightClickedFile in file sameFolder using settings preset "Audio Only"
    end tell 
end tell
```

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you appear to be struggling with Automator, you could maybe consider using `ffmpeg` to convert your files.

To convert `song.wav` in your HOME directory into `song.m4a` at 320kb/s, you can run this in **Terminal**:

```
ffmpeg -i song.wav -c:a aac -b:a 320k song.m4a
```

If that looks good, you can do all the `.wav` file in the current directory with:

```
for f in *.wav; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:a aac -b:a 320k "${f%%.*}.m4a" ; done
```

---

As Apple doesn't provide a package manager, like many folk, I tend to use [homebrew](https://brew.sh). Once you have **homebrew** installed, you can install, remove and maintain many hundreds of packages. You install `ffmpeg` with:

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, how can I convert about 100 wav files with that? can I do it in a row?

Comment: See the line that starts... *"If that looks good..."* in my answer.

Comment: thanks, but i cannot do it. it is even more complicated than idiotic automator